# RSpec: Testing with Threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading, unit-testing, rspec

In RSpec, I have function that creates a new thread, and inside that thread performs some action–in my case, calls `TCPSocket#readline`. Here's the function as it is right now:

```
def read
  Thread.new do
    while line = @socket.readline
      #TODO: stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Due to thread scheduling, my test will fail if written as such:

```
it "reads from socket" do
  subject.socket.should_receive(:readline)
  subject.read
end
```

Currently the only way I know to hack around this is to use `sleep 0.1`. Is there a way to properly delay the test until that thread is running?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your goal is to assert the system state is changed by the execution of your second thread, you should join on the second thread in your main test thread:

```
it "reads from socket" do
  subject.socket.should_receive(:readline)
  socket_thread = subject.read
  socket_thread.join
end
```

Comment: Good call, in my n00bishness I completely forgot about the fact that it was returning the thread, so I didn't think to use it that way.

Comment: And what if the goal is not to wait on the thread to complete? Sort of like this: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2477428 or alternate post http://code.activestate.com/lists/ruby-talk/20264/

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit of a hack, but here's a `before` block you can use in case you'd like the thread to `yield` but be able to call `join` at the end of the thread.

```
before do
  allow(Thread).to receive(:new).and_yield.and_return(Class.new { def join; end }.new)
end
```